# ggplot2 - does stat_summary produce ..y..? How would I subset on y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. Curious - why doesn't stat_summary produce any new variables?  Would seems very useful to have access to the y values, or am I missing something?
2. If I used stat_summary to get the mean of all y's at a given x, is there some way to identify the new y (the means) that is the max/min of all new y's?  So lets say I want points for all means, but then I want to color the highest mean point and the lowest mean point with different colors.  How would I do that?

Comment: Generally, you may find it easier to just append this information to your data frame. Just because it's in there doesn't mean you have to use it. ddply(), apply() could easily accomplish 1, with 2 being accomplished with a clever subset of the same data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Brandon says, I strongly recommend to summarize data by yourself before using ggplot, but you can access the summarized "y" like this:

```
d <- data.frame(expand.grid(x=1:4, rep=1:3), y=rnorm(4*3))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + 
  stat_summary(mapping=aes(colour=factor(ifelse(min(..y..)==..y.., 1, ifelse(max(..y..)==..y.., 3, 2))
)), fun.y=mean, geom="point")
```

maybe this is difficult to understand though.

Comment: @kohske - How did you know that ..y.. was available?  I couldn't find it in documentation.  I'm trying to understand how I go about answering these questions myself =)

Comment: @SFun. Look at Hadley's website for ggplot2. It has details on what transformed variables each `stat` returns. For `stat_summary`, the return values are dependent on the function used. Any function invoked as `fun.y` will only return `..y..`, while using `fun.data` would usually return `y, ymin, ymax`.

Comment: @Ramnath - maybe I'm looking in the wrong place, but I don't see this information here: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_summary.html  the "New variables produced by the statistic" section is empty

Comment: @SFun. to see variables produced by `stat_summary`, just type the name of the function in your R console. For example, type `mean_sdl` and you would see what variables it returns. For other stats the help page is useful. Check `stat_boxplot` out.

Comment: @Ramnath - that doesn't seem to work.  when I type stat_summary I get: function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "pointrange", position = "identity", 
    ...) 
StatSummary$new(mapping = mapping, data = data, geom = geom, 
    position = position, ...)

Comment: @SFun. I meant that it depends on the function you use inside your `stat_summary` call. Some of the custom functions available to use are  `mean_sdl`, `median_hilow`, `mean_se`. You need to type the name of that function to see what it returns. You can always write your own function in which case the return values would be known to you.

Comment: @Ramnath - sorry, I'm still confused.  Could you show me specifically where I can find out that fun.y returns ..y.. ?  I typed "mean" but nothing.

Comment: @SFun. Note my first comment where I mention that any function invoked as fun.y will only return `..y..`, while using `fun.data` would usually return `y, ymin, ymax`. If you are using one of the functions already built into ggplot2 (like `mean_sdl`) then you can see the values it returns by typing `mean_sdl` in your R-Console. Hope this helps

Comment: @Ramnath - ok,  I think what you're saying here is that ..y.. is not documented anywhere (or else I'm missing some R-wide convention that is taken as a given =)  I would just have to know that that var is produced.  My major struggle with ggplot is the holes in documentation.

Comment: @SFun. inferring the ..y.. is tough, but the overall documentation is great and you can always post issues you have either here or on the ggplot2 google group. i believe that all the other .. vars are well documented on hadley's site.