# ggplot2 - possible to reorder x's by value of computed y (stat_summary)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is it possible to reorder x values using a computed y via stat_summary?
I would think that this should work:

```
stat_summary( aes( x = reorder( XVarName , ..y.. ) ) )
```

but I get the following error:
"Error: stat_summary requires the following missing aesthetics: x"

Comment: No, because then `stat_summary` doesn't get an x value as input.

Comment: In general, I've had better (read: more efficient) luck at transforming my data outside of `ggplot` itself when it gets complicated like this.

Comment: @hadley - could you explain further?  I set x =, so why isn't that the input?

Comment: @hadley - also, I'm finding the concepts of statistics generated data and layer generated data to be and what data can and cannot be referenced across layers (i.e. group=1 ) to be confusing.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711100/ggplot2-does-stat-summary-produce-y-how-would-i-subset-on-y/5711767#5711767  In general I think there's a great opportunity to provide some examples that clearly spell out data as it flows through a constructed plot.  I have your book, but still struggle here.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to simultaneously set the input to and the output from `stat_summary`, which you can't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen a number of your posts, and I think this may be helpful for you. When generating a plot, always save it to a unique variable

Create your plots without regard for ordering at first, until you're comfortable just creating the plots. Then, work your way into the structure of the ggplot objects to get a better understanding of what's in them. Then, figure out what you should be sorting.

```
plot1 <- ggplot() + ...
```

You can push plots to the viewport by typing out the object name that you've saved them to:

```
plot1
```

Creating a ggplot object (or variable) allows you the opportunity to review the structure of the plot. Which, incidentally, can answer a number of the questions that you've been having so far.

```
str(plot1)
```

It is still fairly simple to reorder a plot after you've saved it as a variable/object, albeit with slightly longer names:

```
plot$data$variable_tobe_recoded <- factor(...)
```

Comment: great advice!  I didn't think to use str(plot), I was calling summary(plot) but that doesn't give me much information.

Comment: I had similar issues "figuring things out" when I first started with ggplot. Something I didn't add here, that I should have, is that you should be summarizing your data before you pump it into ggplot. Hadley has created two other packages, namely reshape and plyr that make these simple (and even complex) manipulations easy as pie. If you're not familiar with those two packages - that should be a goal for the future. melt(), cast(), reshape(), ddply()

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Isn't it too much to ask you, please, to show an example of ordering the plot via `plot$data$variable_tobe_recoded`?

Comment: well, at it's most basic, there is something like `plot$data$variable_tobe_recoded <- reorder(plot$data$variable_tobe_recoded, some_other_variable_of_same_length)` but really, if you search for questions with ggplot and reorder you'll find all different kinds of scenarios