# ggplot order discrete x by mean of y?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data looks something like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(truth = structure(c(1L, 60L, 60L, 1L, 60L, 1L, 
                                          51L, 60L, 1L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 1L, 60L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 51L, 51L, 
                                          60L, 1L, 51L, 60L, 60L, 51L, 1L, 51L, 51L, 60L, 1L, 51L, 60L, 
                                          60L, 60L, 60L, 51L, 51L, 1L, 51L, 60L, 60L, 51L, 60L, 51L, 1L, 
                                          60L, 60L, 1L, 51L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
                                                                         "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
                                                                         "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
                                                                         "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", 
                                                                         "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", 
                                                                         "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
                                                                         "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", 
                                                                         "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81"), class = "factor"), 
                      Value = c(-30.0770205345024, 11.7433058396476, 7.36998070970907, 
                                -40.9432745219622, 11.2711232296384, 37.654418952948, 52.0790876912742, 
                                9.24338996112739, 29.0493670430368, 49.1051619881392, 44.2985212410612, 
                                43.6318989421322, 65.4604885768842, 8.53340577821466, 28.0911627592635, 
                                -10.9056308891468, -30.7565582432717, -10.6123772579921, 
                                72.062213840367, 48.7134304917154, 5.27055421605771, 84.0339742464238, 
                                44.9513792584612, 8.69314684177602, 4.46763929211751, 67.201960023123, 
                                18.8362161729668, 55.8315346585296, 42.795252431141, 10.6963690858218, 
                                20.4073049396301, 72.4095655954934, 6.57602161344761, 11.3705463495041, 
                                5.75891202331646, 4.4898446961011, 61.9778344010139, 45.713765588086, 
                                -50.570124971873, 65.3016561445738, 13.413626538152, 5.37048273610232, 
                                59.9860827960121, 12.1028140616031, 56.3708005716536, -29.5009161157071, 
                                7.22681794770881, 4.27798086289943, -20.8395270111429, 57.8745694222055
                      )), .Names = c("truth", "Value"), row.names = c(88L, 126L, 
                                                                      288L, 232L, 78L, 76L, 83L, 237L, 52L, 62L, 275L, 194L, 103L, 
                                                                      117L, 262L, 184L, 25L, 205L, 119L, 203L, 15L, 64L, 74L, 225L, 
                                                                      297L, 176L, 277L, 197L, 5L, 105L, 7L, 38L, 12L, 285L, 63L, 201L, 
                                                                      56L, 155L, 247L, 128L, 240L, 72L, 44L, 51L, 29L, 82L, 249L, 57L, 
                                                                      112L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to generate a plot like this

```
df1  %>% ggplot(aes(x=truth, y=Value)) + 
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, mult=1, 
               geom="pointrange", conf.int=0.95) + 
  theme_bw()
```

But I want to reorder "truth" acording to the mean value for each one. In this example 1,60,51.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738619/ggplot2-possible-to-reorder-xs-by-value-of-computed-y-stat-summary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reorder like this

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(reorder(truth, truth),Value)) +
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, mult=1, 
geom="pointrange", conf.int=0.95) +
theme_bw()
```

edited

---

if you want to reorder based on Value column then do this

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(reorder(truth, Value),Value)) +
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, mult=1, 
geom="pointrange", conf.int=0.95) +
theme_bw()
```

And in any case if you want to reorder based on the descending values of Value columns you can do this :)

```
ggplot(data = df1, aes(reorder(truth, -Value),Value))
```

Comment: I tried running that and is not making any difference :(

Comment: Yes. I think Veerandra has a typo. It should be aes(reorder(truth, Value),Value)